# Ionic Thumbnail List render incorrectly

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I use ionic thumbnail list like the document said:
```

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-thumbnail item-start>
    <img src="assets/img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
  <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
  <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
</ion-item>
```

```
I copied same code to my project, when it didn't render correctly.
My list view show like belwo:

And i checked the html ion-item and ion-thumbnail generate is

[image: image|690x407]

It doesn't like ionic example. the ion-thumbnail directive incorrectly wrapped by ion-label.

I don't know what happen, below is my ionic info

```

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.5.0 (/Applications/My-Project/sharemap/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova)
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.0 (/Applications/My-Project/sharemap/node_modules/@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular)
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.6.0 (/Applications/My-Project/sharemap/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils)
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.6.0 (/Applications/My-Project/sharemap/node_modules/ionic)
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 6.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.10.1
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 8.3 Build version 8E162
ios-deploy        : 1.8.1
ios-sim           : 5.0.6
npm               : 3.10.3
```

```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: ion-item suppose to be a child of ion-list. Ex: <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
   ....
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:
I change the `item-start` directive to `item-left`, then problem solved.

i don't why this directive not work like Ionic Document said.

And I also found that `item-end` not work like document either. You need to change to `item-right`.

The right code is below:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-thumbnail item-left>
    <img src="assets/img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <h2>My Neighbor Totoro</h2>
  <p>Hayao Miyazaki • 1988</p>
  <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
</ion-item>
```